# Create dataframe in R from messy excel spreadsheets, with each dataframe starting with specific cell content

Tags: r, dataframe, import, xlsx, readxl

I have a huge number of excel spreadsheets with the same type of content, but the structure has been changed for some. For example, 'Part 2' may be found on the same tab as 'Part 1' in one spreadsheet, while another may have 'Part 2' on a separate spreadsheet.

Is there a way to have any package (readxl, xlsx etc.) find the tab containing a specific cell - "Part 2" - and then import from that cell?

Currently I have:

```
library(readxl)
library(readxl)

path <- "C:\\Documents\\name\\spreadsheet.xlsx"
```

To read in the first two tabs

```
tab1 <- read_excel(path, sheet = 1, range = "A1:E20")
tab2 <- read_excel(path, sheet = 2)
```

Then to identify where to start with Tab 2 Parts 1 and 2

```
part2start <- which(str_detect(tab2$`Part1`, "Part 2")) # this gives a number, e.g. 13L, that shows the cell with "Part 2"

tab2part1 <- read_excel(path, sheet=2, n_max = part2start - 10, skip = 12)
tab2part2 <- read_excel(path, sheet = 2, skip = part2start + 9)
```

However, 'Part 2', which is in tab 2 in the above example, may actually be in tab 3. Is there a way to recognise this on R and then read that in as tab2part2, instead of doing the above?

Thanks very much!

Comment: All of these packages offer functions to read excel files (and enable you to find a particular value in a cell). I'd suggest looking at `openxlsx` since I had most success with this package over others... (but only works for `.xlsx` files). Can you show what you already tried? What are you struggling with?

Comment: You're going to have to import them all in some fashion to be able to look for "Part 2", but once you find it, you can discard the parts you don't need to keep. You could do this inside a call to `lapply` or `map` so you don't have to store all the full versions at once.

Comment: not really an R-answer but it might be easiest time to write a (relatively simple) vba-(=macro)-solution that saves the relevant parts as csv... And then read those into R.

Comment: Hi all - I've updated my code below to try and show what I mean. Hopefully this helps a bit, let me know!